Mousepointer flickers to Busy Circle in Freecad
I just Setup Ubuntu 24.04LTS on a VM and Installed Freecad from the snapstore.
When i hover over the Freecad Window the Mousepointer starts Flickering to the Busy Circle and no inputs are Possible.
Can someone explin why and how to fix?

This may be your issue https://forum.freecad.org/viewtopic.php?style=8&t=87066 they also say it happens in Ubuntu. You can try earlier version of freecad from store.

It may have been a good idea to have checked that the app works with Ubuntu 24.04 before installing it. Many apps have needed to be updated to work with this quite new version of the Ubuntu OS.
